# Finding the certificate thumbprint for a particular website on Chrome through Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Let's say I open a particular website on Chrome through Selenium - www.google.com. I can view the certificate thumbprint for this website manually.
But is it possible to get hold of this thumbprint thru any webdriver apis? Or programatically how would I go about getting the certificate thumbprint for a website?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the security certificates?

Comment: Yes, the security ceritificate whose details can be accessed by right clicking the lock (or the incorrect lock) symbol to the left of the url.

Comment: So I got the access to the webserver and could get the thumbprint value through openssl api. As for getting the thumbprint through chrome webdriver itself, I reached a dead end as the request is still under consideration (or may be not) by the chrome folks.